# Opening Port on OpenShift free gear

Tags: port, openshift, portforwarding

I have installed a java Program on OpenShift free gear
when i start the program, it opens port 29527 to be communicated externally

i have a electronic module which would communicate with this port and send data. the Java Program would then insert the data in mysql db

when i do port-forward i get following
[image]

But still i am not able to communicate with the port

please let me know if i am missing some commands

Thanks & Regards,
Pranav C Lunavat

Comment: with 29527? or mysql?

Comment: What is not working? What is the error message? Looking at the console output it looks like port 29527 is forwarded.